# Convert list to variables in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I am using easygui to get a list of integers from the user. It outputs something like this:

```
fieldValues = [1,2]
```

I want to convert that list to:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. What are you actually trying to do with them?

Comment: What @Blender said, but to do it you could do: `for val in fieldValues: locals()['val{0}'.format(val)] = val`.  But again, you don't want to do that.

Comment: why not just use fieldValues[0] and fieldValues[1] ?

Comment: @sberry don't try and modify `locals` http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Answer (score 0):

(EDITED to explain my reasoning more clearly)

One reason why you might want to convert a list to variables is to make the code more self-documenting. A variable like `password` is easier to understand than `fieldValue[3]`, for instance.

However, as @Blender suggested, it is probably better not to assign the elements of a list to individual variables.

One way to achieve both goals would be to refer to the elements of the list by name rather than by number. In other languages, you could use an enumerated variable (e.g. an `enum` in Java or C#). You could use the [enum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/) package in Python for a fully robust solution or you could do something like this:

```
username, password = range(2)
print(fieldValue[username])
```

Comment: Don't you think that's a little confusing?

Comment: @Blender: I agree it could be confusing with variable names like `var1` but, with more meaningful names that relate to the values being returned from the GUI, it could make the code more readable. I think `fieldValue[password]` is more maintainable than `fieldValue[3]`, for instance.

Comment: Regarding your update: `fieldValue[username]` isn't something I see very much in Python code. `username` alone would be good, but storing constants like that isn't common and can be misleading.

Comment: If you know enough about the list to define such variables to use as list indices, you could just write `username, password = fieldValue`.

Comment: @chepner: +1: Yes, that's a very good point. Indeed, Blender may have been making this point too, though it didn't click with me until now.